# PyTube for Audio and video downloader program

Tags: python, pytube

i have a problem with this program :

from pytube import YouTube

```
while True:
url = YouTube(input("please enter your YouTube LINK : "))
type = YouTube(input("please enter yr type, audio or video : "))
video = url.streams.first().download()
audio = url.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
if type == video:
    print(video)
    break
elif type == audio:
    yt_obj[0].download()
    print(audio)

    break
else :
    print("pls enter audio, or, video :")

print("success")
break
```

i get this msg :  `raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern) pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*`

Answer (score 1):

```
type = input("please enter yr type, audio or video : ")
```

That should fix it :)